# Can you create text based calculated members in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

Is is possible to have a calculated member that shows text instead of numerical values.For instance, classifying customers by the product they bought into Platinum, gold, silver and bronze.
[image]

Is it possible to aggregate the data and show it in the cube in this way?

Comment: Do you have a Tabular or Multidimensional cube? What’s the definition of the Classification calculation?

Comment: Its a multidimensional cube. By definition, do you mean the limits for the calculations? Can we use 
Bronze1 to 5
Silver 6 to 10
Gold 11 to 15
Platinum greater than 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a Multidimensional cube you write the calculated measures in MDX. You can use the [Case function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/case-statement-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16) to build a calculation like this which returns text:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Classification]
AS
Case
 When [Measures].[Volume] >= 1  And [Measures].[Volume] < 6 Then "Bronze"
 When [Measures].[Volume] >= 6  And [Measures].[Volume] < 11 Then "Silver"
 When [Measures].[Volume] >= 11 And [Measures].[Volume] <= 15 Then "Gold"
 When [Measures].[Volume] >  15 Then "Platinum"
End;
```